# Table columns collapsed in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have this function which is responsible of making the table `tr` and `th` collapse. But in fact I don't want to collapse all the table columns `(th and tr)`. I think because I am using `$('tr th').click(function()` so all the `tr` and `th` are collapsing. Is there any way I can exclude some columns? I don't want to move the title..

```
$('tr th').click(function() {

    var index = (this.cellIndex + 1);
    var cells = $('table tr > :nth-child(' + index + ')');
    cells.toggleClass('collapsed');

    if ($(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
        $(this).find('span').html('<b>+</b>');
    }
    else {
        $(this).find('span').html('<b>-</b>');
    }

    if ($('table tr > th:not(.collapsed)').length)
        $('table').removeClass('collapsed');
    else
        $('table').addClass('collapsed');
});
});
```

Here is my code: [jsfiddle.net/9QkVd/20](http://jsfiddle.net/9QkVd/20)

Comment: There are more than one ways you can exclude certain elements or element types. Would be helpful if you can also post the HTML you are trying to work with.

Comment: thank you for your comment please see my code here http://jsfiddle.net/9QkVd/20/ i don't want to move the title..

Comment: Please add your html, and any other relevant code, to your question; Stack Overflow is here for your question, in its entirety, sites such as JS Fiddle are for demonstrations/supporting evidence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To exclude the first column (title), you can use:

```
$('tr th:gt(0)').click(function() {
    ...
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9QkVd/22/

Comment: Or simply `tr th:gt(0)`.

Comment: For that you can simply use `:gt(1)` in the selector. i.e. if you need to select till the Nth column, you use `:gt(N-1)` in the selector.

Comment: thank you so much its working it is working perfectly now ^_^
 Is it possible to click only on the plus or minus symbol to get the action done I don't want to click on the hole th cell.thank you

Comment: Yes, just bind the click event to the span (containing the plus and minus) and do some slight mods inside the handler. Check: http://jsfiddle.net/9QkVd/25/

Answer (score 2):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you want a function that collapses some headers but not all.  See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QAKmG/1/).

All you need to do is slightly modify the selector for your .click function:

```
$('tr th.collapse').click(function() { ... }
```

and add a class `collapsible` onto the headers that you want to have this functionality.  Change your CSS a bit so that your title isn't so large and you're done!